# Database delete operation

Tags: java, sql

I want to perform a simple delete operation on my database but my program becomes busy and it stops responding. I don't know what is going on since it is not displaying the error.

```
private void deleteCustomer(ActionEvent event) {
    String mName = name.getText(); 
    String mID = id.getText();


    Boolean flag = mName.isEmpty() || mID.isEmpty(); 
    if(flag){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR); 
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Please Enter All Fields.");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
    }
     String st = "DELETE CUSTOMER WHERE id = '"+ mID +"'" ;
    System.out.println(st);
    if(handler.execAction(st)){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION); 
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Deleted");
        alert.showAndWait();
        //return;
    }else{
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR); 
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Error Occured");
        alert.showAndWait();

    }
}
```

here is the method I am using to accomplish the task

```
 public boolean execUpdate(String query){
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        if(stmt.executeUpdate(query) == 1){
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data " + message);
            System.out.println("data deleted succefully!!");
        }

        return true; 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error: "+ e.getMessage(), "error occoured", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Exception at execQuery: dataHandler" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return false; 
    }finally{
}


public boolean execAction(String query){
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(query);

        return true; 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error: "+ e.getMessage(), "error occoured", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Exception at execQuery: dataHandler" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return false; 
    }finally{
}
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `execAction`, not for `execUpdate`.

Comment: Try debugging your code and seeing where it stalls to narrow it down

Comment: omg, thank you. that was a stupid mistake

Comment: the program is working now but I can't delete the first row. is that a special case or something?

Comment: Try for mID: `' OR id != '` and then look for SQL injection and PreparedStatement.

Comment: I have to read more about this but I found the reason why I was not able to delete the first row. The row was associated with another table to show customer transaction history. I think I was violating one of the constraints. thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add `FROM` keyword in SQL

```
String st = "DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE id = '"+ mID +"'" ;
```